# Como atualizar um banco de dados sem que a ação parta do cliente?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Não sou muito avançado em php, sql e tudo mais, e me surgiu a seguinte duvida. Supondo que hoje for dia 10 e eu queira que se passar o dia 12 uma informação no BD seja atualizada para 'enviado' por exemplo, se o usuário estiver aberto não tem dificuldade, mas se nenhum usuário entrar no site até dia 20 por exemplo, como faço para que quando chegar tal dia, o próprio servidor faça essa atualização?

Comment: Outra opção seria utilizar `EVENT` do priprio mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você vai precisar é de criar um script, por exemplo em PHP, que execute as regras de negócio que precisa, e agendar esta tarefa em um sistema de Cron Job.

Cron Job é um tipo de Agendador de Tarefas, onde você irá definir a periodicidade e qual rotina deverá ser executada neste período.

Então você pode configurar por exemplo para que essa rotina PHP seja chamada a cada 1 minuto, fazendo assim um processamento independente de acessos de usuários.

Existem diversos clientes de Cron Job, inclusive já embutidos em hospedagens, sistemas Linux e Unix.

Comment: Intendi, com isso eu poderia executar qualquer scrip correto! Se aplica no envio de email agendados e varias outras coisas né? Vou dar uma aprofundada em Cron Job. Vlw mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria guardar essa data em uma coluna do banco de dados e quando for necessário saber se passou ou não dois dias basta verificar com uma cláusula `WHERE`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE NOW() > '$data';
```